# How to open settings->messages->unknown & spam programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I know it's possible to open the settings app in Swift. For example:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=General&path=About")!)
```

I'd like to open settings->messages->unknown & spam.
"Messages" opens using "App-Prefs:root=Messages", but I can't find the correct path for unknown & spam. I tried finding the path myself, and I've also searched the web but found only partial lists of settings' paths.

It should be mentioned that I have no intention of uploading my app to the app store.

What's the way to open this entry?

Comment: I don't have a section called Unknown & Spam in the settings app on iOS 10 or iOS 11.

Comment: It's under "Messages". I have a message filter installed and it creates entries there, but I think "Unknown & Spam" should be there anyway

Comment: It seems that the section in Settings might only be available if there is actually a filtered message.

Comment: OK, thanks, would still love an answer from someone who knows (or knows how to find out what the path is)

Comment: How do I install the message filter?

Comment: I wrote the filter I have, so I don't know how you should get one

Answer (score 1):

I was using this successfully, `App-Prefs:root=MESSAGES` to open "Message Settings" and it was working on Beta 1 and Beta 3... But stopped working on BETA 3.

I couldn't find a way to open the "Unknown & Spam" yet...

Comment: Do you get any way to redirect app to Setting-> Messages-> Unknown & Spam?